# Modal popup when click notification snooze button, without open app react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, alarm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buliR.jpg)

Above image another app how to implement in react native.

How to open above imagepopup in react native without open application?

When click notification action button click modal open in background without open app

Any idea please help me